# Change style of nav active section in jQuery One Page Nav Plugin

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to change the style of the active section of the menu in a landing page.

I am using the jQuery One Page Nav Plugin you can find in here: http://github.com/davist11/jQuery-One-Page-Nav

My site is currently this: www.gewexhibition.com

I am trying to make the small circles from the navigation menu change color when they are active so the user knows where he or she is on the page at every moment.

I have been trying different things with CSS but I am not able to make it work. The most I have accomplish was to get the square around the circle in a different color when you clicked on it.

This is the menu code:

```
<ul id="navi">
            <li  class="current" ><a href="#top"><span class="tooltip">top</span></a></li>
            <li><a class="cir" href="#about"><span class="tooltip">about us</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#wedo"><span class="tooltip">what we do</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#clients"><span class="tooltip">clients</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact"><span class="tooltip">contact us</span></a></li>
        </ul>
```

Hope somebody can help me. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using `:focus`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery plugin adds a `current` class to the active list item in which you are, so the only thing you need to do is to make the styles in the css like this

```
#navi .current {
  background: red;
}
```

You can check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ym41215f/3/)

Comment: That was perfect but it had missing that I only wanted to change the color of the circe, not the entire section. So I used this: #navi .current a{
  background: #00b6dc;
}